# Multiple TableViewControllers & Segues

Tags: ios, xcode

I have a `TableView` that is populated with data. When a user taps a row, a new `TableView` opens with more data to choose from. This data changes based on the row the user taps. Much like an application where the user chooses from a list of car makes, and then models. Is it possible to handle a situation like that with a `TableViewController` for the car makes, and 1 `TableViewController` for the models? Or would there be 1 `TableViewController` for the makes, and then a separate `TableViewController` for each make's set of models? I don't know the best way to approach this :-( I'm making an app of my own which is very similar in structure and I can't seem to find any documentation on how to accomplish this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Im looking for more of a complex style table application. A set of stores leads to a set of names based on the store choice, and then leads to a single view screen which prompts for a pin. Data is from an external source being fed in with NSURL and NSData. I am able to get the store table populated. I just need to figure out how to get the second TableView to populate based on the store choice.

Comment: My answer below goes into that.  You use the performSegueWithIdentifier method to set the data on the new view controller (based on the selection from the current one).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, your models controller would serve for all makes. It would be passed an ID of the make requested and then fetch the necessary data accordingly.

Something like this might be of some help:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewAndDataModel/TableViewAndDataModel.html

But I think the foundation of your problem is not necessarily to be found in a working example of your exact needs, but more in general tutorials for ios development.

Sorry if I have assumed you're just beginning ios development. I might be able to improve this answer if a more specific need is clarified (like how do I pass the ID to the model controller) etc

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I will look through the link you posted and go from there. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

In general - this approach would utilize a separate `UITableViewController` for each data level and use a `UINavigationController` to handle the transitions between the different view controllers.

This process used to involve a lot of boilerplate code, but it is now aided by StoryBoards.  You can setup each level in a storyboard and handle the transitions and setup data for the next view in `performSegueWithIdentifier:`.

You can see a tutorial here on using StoryBoards: http://kurrytran.blogspot.com/2011/10/ios-5-storyboard-uitableview-tutorial.html

You can see another Sample From Apple that demonstrates the data drill down with a Storyboard: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleDrillDown/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007416-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2

Comment: The drill down is somewhat of help, but it takes a table view and drills down to detail view. Im looking for more of a table view to table view to detail view.